# Converting a Swf to a Image

Tags: flash, coldfusion, adobe

Is there a application (Or way in coldfusion/VB.net) to be able to convert a swf to a image file? It needs to be ok quality and needs not to be too slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://bytescout.com/products/developer/swftoimagesdk/swftoimage.html

Example Code (using fixed preload time)

```vb
Set SWFToImage = CreateObject("SWFToImage.SWFToImageObject")
SWFToImage.InputSWFFileName = "PRELOAD1://movie_with_dynamic_data.swf"
SWFToImage.ImageOutputType = 1 ' set output image type to Jpeg (0 = BMP, 1 = JPG, 2 = GIF)

SWFToImage.Execute_Begin ' start conversion
SWFToImage.FrameIndex = 1 ' set frame index
SWFToImage.Execute_GetImage
SWFToImage.SaveToFile "movie_with_dynamic_data.jpg"
SWFToImage.Execute_End ' end conversion
```

Answer (score 2):

You can export directly from Adobe flash to PNG.

Or you can use [swftools](http://swftools.org/).

```
swfrender file.swf -o output.png
```

Comment: I'll look into it, although i would like to avoid things you have to install.